# Some keyboard buttons stop working [linux]

Tags: keyboard, linux-mint

From time to time, some keys [e, g, h, Fn, numpad 8] suddenly stop *working* (continuously pressing them doesn't even trigger an interrupt - consulted `/proc/interrupts`). Also, this happens almost every time after resuming from sleep. After a while (a few seconds), everything works normally.

This doesn't happen on Windows 10, so my guesses are:

- kernel bug
- Mint 18.3 bug
- some application *stealing* key-presses (?)

Any suggestions for where I can look into?

```
kernel: 4.13.0-38
OS: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia
laptop: Lenovo Legion Y520
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the solutino shown at this link: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=222009

Comment: Unfortunately, `i8042.nomux=1` doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a hardware problem, confirmed by many other users of the [Lenovo forum](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops/Lenovo-Legion-Y520-Keyboard/td-p/3631381). I have managed to solve it by:

- making sure the iron sheet covering the RAM isn't touching the keyboard connector
- placing a small plastic film underneath the keyboard connector, so that it won't touch any conductor